# Optimal way to reduce any one number to 0

Tags: algorithm, math

Given two numbers `n` and `m`, only one operation is allowed i.e

We can only subtract a multiple of the smaller number and it cannot be zero, i.e. at least 1 has to be subtracted each turn.

How to find the optimal path to reduce any one of the numbers to 0?

I tried to use the following rules:

- if `gcd(m, n) == min(m, n)` then 1 turn
- if `(n % (m % n) == 0 and n + (m % n) < m)` then 2 turns

```
if(__gcd(a, b) == min(a, b) || __gcd(a, b) == 1 || (n % (m % n) == 0 && n + (m % n) < m))
   cout << "Win";
else
   cout << "Lose";
```

The expected result shows if someone starts from the beginning and 2 players are playing whether the first player wins or loses, considering each one plays optimally

For e.g

```
1 1
Win
4 4
Win
4 6
Lose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question statement,there are two cases only:

1. if smaller number start game,he will win in 1st move.
2. If large number start game,then 
   if gcd(m,n) == min(m,n)
   then Larger wins in 1st move 
   else 
   in Second move small will win

Comment: I.m sorry, i guess my statement wasn't clear enough the player can use any of the two numbers and has to reduce any one to 0

Comment: I am sorry but your statement is still not clear because according to your statement there is only 1 solution which i think is incorrect.Please edit and paste full problem statement so that whole community could understand your real problem.Thanks